# Admin Page for Email Notifications (Activating / Deactivating Workflow Rules from Visualforce)

Tags: visualforce

I currently have a workflow rule that calls an email alert on one of my objects. This is working fine, however, my client wants the ability to turn on / off this email notification from a visualforce page, as well as the ability to add / remove email recipients independent from what the email alert is set to. Note that these admin settings should apply to *all* objects, not just one.

Now, this is definitely possible if, say, I added fields to this object to store those settings. However, this would only affect *that* particular record, and not *every* record universally.

Is there a way to activate / deactivate a workflow rule from a Visualforce page, as well as some of the settings on that workflow rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others will chime in on how you can do this with the MetaData API ([see GitHub](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) for an Apex wrapper) but perhaps you should rethink this to something simpler

1. Use a hierarchical custom setting to enable/disable the workflow (the custom setting is one of the fields used in `Formula Evaluates to true` setup.  You could create a trivial VF page to manage that custom settings value.
2. Use a Field of type Email on the object whose value defaults to some distribution list.  Give your client the ability to add/remove members from the distro list using the tools provided by your mail system.  The email alert references the field of type email.

For example, on Opportunity, you could have a custom field called On_closed_won_notify__c of type = Email. The value would be "closedWonEmailDistroList@mycompany.com"  This distribution list email address has members managed by your email system (like Microsoft Exchange's address book). Give your manager access to the tool that manages corporate email distro lists - which in most companies has some self-service feature). The Workflow email alert action sends the email to the value of Opportunity.on_closed_won_notifiy__c

Comment: #1 is definitely a solution and I've got that working now. as for #2, I'm not quite sure what you mean. 'using the tools provided by your mail system'? couldn't I continue to use the custom setting approach, defaulting these email fields to custom setting fields that could be edited on a trivial VF page?

Comment: Email Alerts can't send emails except to specific field types (like owner, related Contact, TeamMembers, etc) and any field on the triggering object of type = Email. There is also the 'additional emails' section of the email alert but that is just text. I added to the answer to address #2